# Como puedo mostrar la fecha como esta almacenada en FireStore ya que me aparece Timestamp(seconds=1664923290, nanoseconds=1500000)

Tags: flutter, dart

Actualmente hice un formulario para que el usuario seleccione los síntomas que presenta, estos síntomas se almacenan en firestore junto con la fecha en que se guardaron los datos, lo que deseo es que al mostrar esos datos aparezca la fecha y si me aparease pero no con el formato como esta en firestore, colocare una foto de como esta en firestore y como me la muestra en la app.

```
                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();

                  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
                  void _showDatePicker() {
                    showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2025),
                    ).then((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        dateTime = value!;
                      });
                    });
                  }
```

Aca los almaceno:

```
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await users.add({
              'Fatiga': fatiga,
              'Miccion': miccion,
              'Flujo Vaginal': flujoVaginal,
              'Estreñimiento': estrenimiento,
              'Acidez Gastrica': acidezGastrica,
              'Sangrado Nasal': sangradoNasal,
              'Sangrado de encias': sangradoEncias,
              'Hinchazon': hinchazon,
              'Problemas respiratarios': problemasRespiratorios,
              'Fecha ingreso sintoma': dateTime
            }).then((value) => (value) => print('User added'));
          },
          child: Text("Guardar"))
```

Aca es donde genero la fecha y la almaceno.

```
             ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.size,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('''
                    'Los sitomas que presenta son:
                     Fatiga: ${data.docs[index]['Fatiga']}
                     Acidez Gastrica: ${data.docs[index]['Acidez Gastrica']}
                     Fecha de sintoma: ${data.docs[index]['Fecha ingreso sintoma']} 
                   ''');
```

y aca es donde la muestro.

Aca esta como se guarda en firestore.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la app me la muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase almacena la hora como Timestamp, que no es lo mismo que el DateTime que usa Dart/Flutter.

Lo que tendrías que hacer es pasar de Timestamp a DateTime:
`DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(data.docs[index]['Fecha ingreso sintoma']).toString();`

Después para dar formato a la fecha, necesitas un package externo, que deberás instalar en el pubspec: [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

Una vez instalado, para formatear la fecha, tienes que seguir un proceso como este:

```dart
main() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted); // something like 2013-04-20
}
```

Origen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126579/how-do-i-format-a-date-with-dart

A la clase `DateFormat` tendrás que pasarle una cadena de caracteres con el formato de salida que desees. Te dejo un enlace para que profundices más en las opciones que te ofrece DateFormat para dar formato: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Recuerda que si mi pregunta te ha servido y crees que es la correcta, marcarla como tal. De esa forma, fomentas el buen uso del sitio y a que otras personas puedan beneficiarse de tu pregunta.